# MasterDetail page Master behaviour change not working in iPhone devices.How to Change it to popover?

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.forms, master-detail

MasterDetail page Master behaviour change not working in iPhone devices. it always showing the master page below the detail page while sliding. I need master page slide above the detail page.

```
<MasterDetailPage
x:Class="testMasterDetail.Views.MainPage"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:views="clr-namespace:testMasterDetail.Views"
MasterBehavior="Popover"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <views:MenuPage />
</MasterDetailPage.Master>
<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
        <NavigationPage.Icon>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
                <On Platform="iOS" Value="tab_feed.png" />
            </OnPlatform>
        </NavigationPage.Icon>
        <x:Arguments>
            <views:ItemsPage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the default behavior in `iOS` and the `MasterBehavior` does not have any influence on an iPhone. It works in an iPad.

There is already [an issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6498) there in GitHub of Xamarin.forms. You can follow it and add some comments to ask for more information.

Here are some thread which may help: [xamarin-forms-slide-up-master-detail-page](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/105638/xamarin-forms-slide-up-master-detail-page) and [Master-detail menu - slide over top of detail page on iOS](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/100963/master-detail-menu-slide-over-top-of-detail-page-on-ios)